# Select List in AngularJs

Tags: angular

I have an template Driven form in my Angular application, I tried a lot but I am not able to figure out what wrong with my code.

I want to return the selected value from select list and save it to the Firebase database.I have 5 input fields all fields are returning the data and i am able to save to the Firebase except select list value whose data returns as undefined.

This is my template-driven form code:

```
<div class="formalign">
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
     <input ngModel name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <!--for Price-->
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="price">Price</label>
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">INR</span>
        <input ngModel name="price" id="price" type="number" class="form-control">
      </div>
  </div>
  <!--category-->
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="catagory">Catagory</label>
       <select ngModel name="catagory" id="catagory" class="form-control">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option *ngFor="let c of valuearray"  [value]="c.$key">
           {{c.name}}
         </option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <!--Image-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Image</label>
         <input ngModel name="imageurl" id="image" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <!--Save Button-->
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

After clicking on Save button catagory select list returns undefined value.
How i can resolve that?

Below is my Two-way data bidning update with component code:-

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="catagory">Catagory</label>
       <select  [(ngModel)]="catagoryData" name="catagoryData" id="catagoryData" class="form-control">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option *ngFor="let c of valuearray"  [value]="c.$key">
           {{c.name}}
         </option>
       </select>
    </div>
```

In my component.ts i am trying to print the value but it is still giving me undefined value:-

```
catagoryData:string;
    console.log("The Catagory",this.catagoryData);
```

Comment: Change the option code [value] to [ngValue]. Are you initializing the categoryData value in the ngOnInit()? Does the value of categoryData have a matching value to what you are setting in the option?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the two-way data binding example from [Angular Template Driven Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms#two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel). You need to two-way bind your select's ngModel to a property on your controller, in this case model.power.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="power">Hero Power</label>
  <select class="form-control"  id="power"
          required
          [(ngModel)]="model.power" name="power">
    <option *ngFor="let pow of powers" [value]="pow">{{pow}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried your solution ,i have attach updated code in my question but it is still giving me an undefined